# why my calculations are not correct

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form and a Javascript but this Javascript performs an incorrect calculation

```js
function hitung(){

var e = (document.getElementById("ifin").value);
var panjang = parseFloat (document.getElementById("ipanjang").value);
var tinggi = parseFloat (document.getElementById("itinggi").value);
var ht = 2.0;
var hf = 0.0;
var total = 0.0;

if (e == "hpl") {
  hf = 0.0;
}
else if (e == "cat") {
  hf = 0.5;
}
else {
  hf = 0.0;
}
total = panjang*tinggi*ht+hf;
document.getElementById("ototal").innerHTML =
  "Harga Total : Rp." + total.toFixed(2) + "0.000,00" + "<br>Sudah termasuk ongkir";
```

```html
<select name="ifin" id="ifin" class="form-control input-lg" required >
  <option selected disabled >Select Finishing</option>
  <option value="hpl">HPL</option>
  <option value="cat">Cat Duco</option>
</select>
<br>
<h3 align="center"> Masukkan Ukuran </h3>
<div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-xs-6" align="center">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Panjang" min="1" id="ipanjang" >
  </div>
 <div class="col-xs-6">
    <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Tinggi" min="1" id="itinggi">
  </div>
</div>
```

The result is not what I wanted, the `hf` does not count, which counts only `panjang*tinggi*hf`

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: as written in `total`

Comment: Either you write clear question, or we can close it as there is no clear message what is your question, what is expected output and what is actual output.

Comment: i'm so sorry my English is not good

Answer (score 0):

I believe something wrong with your 
    var e = document.getElementById("ifin").value;
Try exclude the bracket.

Comment: what do u mean bracket?

Comment: var e = document.getElementById("ifin").value;

Comment: is it true you write `panjangtinggiht+hf` or just a typo

Answer (score 0):

You must select the `select` tag first then extract the valid option

`var e = document.getElementById("ifin")`

`var rm = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value`

`if(rm == "hpl") {//do stuff}`

Comment: then i write `panjang*tinggi*ht*rm`?

Comment: `function hitung(){

var e = document.getElementById("ifin");
var panjang = parseFloat (document.getElementById("ipanjang").value);
var tinggi = parseFloat (document.getElementById("itinggi").value);
var ht = 2.0;
var hf = 0.0;
var total = 0.0;
var rm = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
if (rm == "hpl") {
  hf = 0.0;
}
else if (rm == "cat") {
  hf = 0.5;
}
else {
  hf = 0.0;
}
total = panjang*tinggi*ht+hf;
document.getElementById("ototal").innerHTML =
  "Harga Total : Rp." + total.toFixed(2) + "0.000,00" + "<br>Sudah termasuk ongkir";`

Answer (score 0):

```js
   

 function hitung(){

    var e = (document.getElementById("ifin").value);
    var panjang = parseFloat (document.getElementById("ipanjang").value);
    var tinggi = parseFloat (document.getElementById("itinggi").value);
    var ht = 2.0;
    var hf = 0.0;
    var total = 0.0;

    if (e == "hpl") {
      //hf = 0.0;
      hf = 1.0;//I wanted 3rd value to make sure it works
    }
    else if (e == "cat") {
      hf = 0.5;
    }
    else {
      hf = 0.0;
    }
document.getElementById("hf").innerHTML = "HF = " + hf;
    total = panjang*tinggi*ht+hf;
    document.getElementById("ototal").innerHTML =
      "Harga Total : Rp." + total.toFixed(2) + "0.000,00" + "<br>Sudah termasuk ongkir";
}
```

```html
   

 <select name="ifin" id="ifin" class="form-control input-lg" required >
      <option selected disabled >Select Finishing</option>
      <option value="hpl">HPL</option>
      <option value="cat">Cat Duco</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <h3 align="center"> Masukkan Ukuran </h3>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-xs-6" align="center">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Panjang" min="1" id="ipanjang" >
      </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Tinggi" min="1" id="itinggi">
      </div>
    </div>
<button onclick="hitung()">Calculate</button>
<h2 id="ototal"></h2>
<h2 id="hf"></h2>
```

Your code looks fine for me, I added a button calculate that will output the value along with `hf`, run the snippet and choose the values and press calculate, you'll see the value.

Answer (score -1):

did you try change the value of hf? it says that the value of hf is floating point value or zero values. change that to non-negative value then try it again

Comment: Answers are not for debate or comments. Write comment instead.

Comment: don't downvote me for answering questions  I just got here 2 months ago... and it needs 50 reputation to add a comment to a question..

Comment: @EmigerSaromsel then you have to post useful answer, sorry. If you edit it to a good answer, I will remove downvote.

Comment: @tilz0R no problem next time i'm improved my answer thank you for removing downvote :D